# I don't want to render the form tag

Tags: asp.net

I would really like to disable the rendering for the form tag.  Basically asp.net will be providing read only pages which should be very clean. i.e, no form tags required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take it out of the markup then.  I don't think it's required if you're only providing read-only access.  I'm able to create straight .aspx files on the web server without the form tag, and they work fine.  Don't expect your postbacks to work, though.

Comment: OK Thanks, that was simple.  For some reason I thought that you would not be allowed to do that!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc)?  It is designed for just this kind of thing...

ASP.NET WebForms does not work well without the main form (ViewState, PostBack, etc. will fail horribly).  I think you may be using the wrong tool for your problem.

Comment: Yes I have looked into MVC however on this occasion it is some simple maintence work on an existing tool

Answer (score 0):

We have some read-only pages in a system, and we simply fetch the data from our DB as XML and apply an XSLT stylesheet to this. Might be overkill for you however.

Alternatively, why not just remove the  tag? Or use an HTML page?

Comment: well the content is not static, so a static html will not do..
Basically I am putting together a simple template mechanism.